# Does a Mexican citizen studying in the US with an FAA license need a visa when landing at airports in Canada?

Tags: usa, international, canada

I'm from Mexico but worked in San Francisco for 4 years under a TN Visa. During that time I learned how to fly and obtained a PPL and then an IFR rating.

I'm now living in Boston getting a Masters Degree under an F1 Visa. I'm interested in flying into Canada. Canada requires visas for Mexican citizens, but a friend claims that there's an exception for pilots. I only want to check out Montreal, so I would be in Canada for 48-72 hours max.

What's a good resource to see visa requirements for pilots from different countries flying into countries other than their own?

Thanks!

Comment: Meta question: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/is-immigration-customs-advice-specific-to-pilots-on-topic-here

Answer (score 4):

You should call the Embassy of Canada in Mexico for advice on your situation. They will best be able to advise a Mexican passport holder on their entry requirements. Their number is +52 55 5724 7900.

Comment: This is almost a link-only answer, but not quite...

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would consider this to be travel advice rather than aviation advice.

Comment: I don't see where you're going with that...?

Comment: @MarkyMark -- pilots get treated somewhat differently under immigration law for fairly obvious reasons, so I wouldn't call it completely off-topic here

Comment: I can't speak for that specific case but I do remember a friend of mine flying to Russia from Germany (not Mathias Rust...). For a simple touch and go he wouldn't have needed any visa. But leaving the plane under whatever circumstances is immigration and thus requires all the papers any other immigration would. Furthermore: As a private pilote you do normally not qualify for the pilot visa as they are often restricted to the staff of airlines recognised as such by the respective authorities.

Answer (score 4):

Canada's immigration website is [quite clear](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Mexico): if your passport lists your nationality as Mexican, you need a visa to enter Canada.

In general, a visa for one country will not affect whether or not you need a visa to visit another country; in this case, your F1 does not change the fact that you need to get a Canadian visiting visa. I have no idea whether it would affect how easily or quickly you're able to get it, though.

Some countries, such as [the US](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas/visas/categories-and-requirements/air-or-ships-crew.html), have a special visa for air crews, and private pilots might qualify in some of those countries.

Comment: In some cases, the special visa is *more* than you need if you aren't a pilot (e.g. Canada-US, where Canadians don't normally need a US visa).

Comment: @cpast the [State department website](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/canada-bermuda.html) has a list of reasons why Canadian citizens might need a visa, and that list doesn't say anything about pilots needing visas...

Comment: I stand corrected for Canada. However, VWP countries aren't exempt from this visa; an airline exec from the UK going to a conference in the US needs no visa, but a British pilot flying an airliner there does.